# How to RSA encode large data in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, large-files, pycrypto

I try to encrypt data with python3.x using pycrypto library. It works fine for short data but not for long arrays. How can I encrypt long data? Should I write a wrapper to split data smaller chunks? Or is there any other crypto library that can handle long data?

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random

random_generator = Random.new().read
key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
publickey = key.publickey() 

"""
Shorter (128 bytes)
"""
msg = b'abcd'*32
print(msg)          # b'abcdabcdabcd...
enc=publickey.encrypt(msg, 32)
print(enc)          # Depends on key. Ex.: (b"hd\n\xbb\xe4\x8b...
dec=key.decrypt(enc)
print(dec)          # b'abcdabcdabcdabcda...

if msg==dec:        # TRUE
    print('TRUE')
else:
    print('FALSE')

"""
LONGER (132 bytes)
"""
msg = b'abcd'*33
print(msg)          # b'abcdabcdabcd...
enc=publickey.encrypt(msg, 32)
print(enc)          # Depends on key. Ex.: (b'\xa2J1;\xd4`\xc5i\x...   
dec=key.decrypt(enc)
print(dec)          # Depends on key. Ex.: b'|*\xb85\\B\\r2\xea\...   

if msg==dec:        # FALSE
    print('TRUE')
else:
    print('FALSE')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the exact answer for the original question but this solved my problem:
Based on https://security.stackexchange.com/a/10953

> ... public-key cryptography is expensive for large messages; the public key algorithm is only used to encrypt the symmetric key and to sign a digest of the file.

So it is not recommended to encrypt large data/files using RSA. Use AES instead:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
obj = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
message = "The answer is no"*32
ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
print(ciphertext)
# '\xd6\x83\x8dd!VT\x92\xaa`A\x05\xe0\x9b\x8b\xf1'
obj2 = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
print(obj2.decrypt(ciphertext))
# 'The answer is no'
```

Comment: Note, this could be too low-level. For example [bad things](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10511) [may happen](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26793) if you'll reuse key and IV and encrypt multiple messages with those. You'll also need a good random number source (or key-stretching function), as a poor biased RNG may undermine the security. Etc etc. I'd suggest to take a look at [cryptography.io](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) package which contains both low-level primitives (shall you need them) and high-level stuff that's generally safe to use without knowing the gory details.